# addStoreFilter not working with custom collection

Tags: magento-1.8, collection, custom

I am using `addStoreFilter` with my custom collection but it won't work.

it gives null result.

My DB column name is `store_id`

for specific store it store like `1,2,3` abd for all store it will store `0`

code is as below.

```
 $collection=Mage::getModel('productline/productline')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status','1')
    ->setOrder('sort_order','ASC')
    ->addStoreFilter();
```

Please help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use it like below.

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
$collection=Mage::getModel('productline/productline')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status','1')
    ->setOrder('sort_order','ASC')
    ->addFieldToFilter('store_id',
        array(
            array('finset'=> array('0')),
            array('finset'=> array($storeId)),
        )
    ));
```